# Three six-sided dice are rolled. Denote the greatest value rolled to be x and the smallest value rolled to be y. What is the expected value of x-y?

Tags: probability, elementary-probability

Three six-sided dice are rolled. Denote the greatest value rolled to be $x$ and the smallest value rolled to be $y$. What is the expected value of $x-y$?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not sure how to go about this.

I listed out all the possible differences. One 5, two 4's, three 3's, four 2's, five 1's, and six 0's. The total of these values is $35$ and there are $21$ different outcomes. Does this make sense?

Comment: What is the possible set of values that $x-y$ can take on?  Did you attempt to list out some of the ways that these values can happen?

Comment: They range from 0 to 5

Comment: The second part of @abiessu's suggestion was the important one.

Comment: I listed out all the possible differences. One 5, two 4's, three 3's, four 2's, five 1's, and six 0's

Comment: In a crude empirical test with 12000 runs, I got the following frequency for $x-y$: 0 (331), 1 (1673), 2 (2634), 3 (3019), 4 (2723), 5 (1620). So I put my money on **3**.

Comment: Three is the expected value?

Comment: It might simplify things to know E(x-y) = E(x) - E(y).

Comment: I don't know what that means. How can I set this up with the information I have obtained?

Comment: I'm working on an answer, this is a lot of counting so give me some time :)

Answer (score 3):

To get a maximum value of $1$ you need to get all $1's$ with probability $\frac{1}{6}^3$.

To get a maximum value of $2$ you need to either get all $2$'s, one $2$ and two $1$'s, or two $2$'s and one $1$ with probability $$\frac{1+{3\choose{2}}+{3\choose{1}}}{6^3}$$

To get a maximum of $3$, you need to either get all $3$'s, two of the other two numbers and a $3$, two of one of the other two numbers and a $3$, or two $3$'s and one of the other two numbers, giving a probability of 
$$\frac{1+3!{2\choose{2}}+{3\choose{2}}{2\choose{1}}+{3\choose{1}}{2\choose{1}}}{6^3}$$

To get a maximum of $4$, you need to either get all $4$'s, two of the other three numbers and a $4$, two of one of the other three numbers and a $4$, or two $4$'s and one of the other three numbers, giving a probability of

$$\frac{1+3!{3\choose{2}}+{3\choose{2}}{3\choose{1}}+{3\choose{1}}{3\choose{1}}}{6^3}$$

To get a maximum of $5$, you need to either get all $5$'s, two of the other four numbers and a $5$, two of one of the other four numbers and a $5$, or two $5$'s and one of the other four numbers, giving a probability of $$\frac{1+3!{4\choose{2}}+{3\choose{2}}{4\choose{1}}+{3\choose{1}}{4\choose{1}}}{6^3}$$

To get a maximum of $6$, you need to either get all $6$'s, two of the other five numbers and a $6$, two of one of the other five numbers and a $6$, or two $6$'s and one of the other five numbers, giving a probability of

$$\frac{1+3!{5\choose{2}}+{3\choose{2}}{5\choose{1}}+{3\choose{1}}{5\choose{1}}}{6^3}$$

Summing these I get $$E(X)=\left(1\cdot\frac{1}{6^3}\right)+\left(2\cdot\frac{7}{6^3}\right)+\left(3\cdot\frac{19}{6^3}\right)+\left(4\cdot\frac{37}{6^3}\right)+\left(5\cdot\frac{61}{6^3}\right)+\left(6\cdot\frac{91}{6^3}\right)\approx 4.958$$

Checking that the numerators sum to $6^3 = 216$, I get

$$1+7+19+37+61+91=216$$

By symmetry, the expected value of the minimum is $$4.958-3.5\approx2.0417$$

Thus $$E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)\approx4.958-2.0417 \approx 2.916$$

**Note:** Needs to be checked!

An excel simulation with about $1$,$000$ trials gives an expected value of the minimum as being $2.048$, an expected value of the maximum as being $4.99$, and a mean difference of $2.88$ which I would say agrees with my result.

Comment: I don't follow the answer, but my empirical test mentioned in comment also gave 2.915833 as the average value of $x-y$ against your 2.916 .

Comment: Could you share how you did your simulation? I don't know any other ways than excel and it takes awhile to scroll down 1000 rows.

Comment: I posted it as an answer, of course it isn't a valid mathematical answer.

Comment: Considering there are only 216 combinations, if you're going to use excel you might as well check every result instead of 1,000 options.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I made 3 columns of a random number between 1 and 6, made a new column with the minimum, a new column with the maximum, and took the average of the 4th and 5th columns.

Comment: I think that @Jesse means that you could make an exhaustive listing of all 216 equiprobable outcomes, from which you could numerically calculate the exact result, rather than a simulation, which would always have some random noise in its result.  (But the result is right: $630/216 = 2.91\overline{6}$.)

Comment: Oh right. That makes sense. I don't know how to do that in excel though.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly easier way of counting:

Rolling the dice one at a time, there are $216$ possible outcomes (sequences of three numbers), each of which has $\frac{1}{216}$ probability to occur.

Of the $216$ possible outcomes there is exactly $1^3 = 1$ in which all rolls are less than $2,$ and in that outcome the maximum is $1.$

There are exactly $2^3 = 8$ outcomes in which all rolls are less than $3.$
Of those outcomes, we have already found $1$ with maximum $1$;
the other $7$ have maximum $2.$

There are exactly $3^3 = 27$ outcomes in which all rolls are less than $4.$
Of those outcomes, we have already found $8$ in which the maximum is either $1$ or $2$; the other $19$ have maximum $3.$

Similarly, we have $4^3 - 3^3 = 64 - 27 = 37$ outcomes with maximum $4,$
$5^3 - 4^3 = 125 - 64 = 61$ outcomes with maximum $5,$ and
$6^3 - 5^3 = 216 - 125 = 89$ outcomes with maximum $6.$

The expected value of the maximum roll comes out to
\begin{align}
E(\max) &= \frac{1}{216}(1(1^3) + 2(2^3 - 1^3) + 3(3^3 - 2^3) + 4(4^3 - 3^3)
  + 5(5^3 - 4^3) + 6(6^3 - 5^3))\\
&= \frac{1}{216}((1-2)1^3 + (2-3)2^3 + (3-4)3^3 + (4-5)4^3 + (5-6)5^3 + 6\cdot6^3)\\
&= \frac{1}{216}(6^4 - (1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3))\\
&= \frac{1}{216}\left(6^4 - \frac14\cdot 5^2\cdot 6^2\right)\\
&= \frac{6^4 - 225}{216}\\
&= \frac{1071}{216}\\
&\approx  4.958333.
\end{align}

Note that this method is easily extended to larger numbers of dice or larger numbers of faces on each die.

As already observed in another answer, the expected value of the minimum is 
$E(\min) = 7 - E(\max),$ so we have
\begin{align}
E(\max - \min) &= E(\max) - E(\min)\\
 &= E(\max) - (7 - E(\max))\\
 &= 2E(\max) - 7\\
 &\approx 2.916666.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is E(min)=7-E(max) and why do we multiply by 2?

Comment: I see why E(min)=7-E(max) now.

Comment: I don't see where the multiplication by 2 comes from.

Comment: @ddswsd He is just factoring. $E(max)-(7-E(max))=2E(max)-7$

Answer (score 1):

I can't put this in comment, but was asked by @Remy to show my empirical solution, which is in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RUNS 12000

int main()
{
    int i, a, b, c, maxv, minv, diff, tot = 0;
    int count[6] = { 0 };
    for(i=0; i<RUNS; i++) {
        a = 1 + rand() % 6;
        b = 1 + rand() % 6;
        c = 1 + rand() % 6;

        maxv = a;
        if(maxv < b) maxv = b;
        if(maxv < c) maxv = c;

        minv = a;
        if(minv > b) minv = b;
        if(minv > c) minv = c;

        diff = maxv - minv;
        count[diff]++;
        tot += diff;
    }
    printf("Average %f\n", (double)tot / RUNS);

    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        printf("%d %4d\n", i, count[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Average 2.915833
0  331
1 1673
2 2634
3 3019
4 2723
5 1620
```

---

**Edit:** since I overlooked that there are 216 combinations, I modified the code to include them all instead of pseudo random throws.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a, b, c, maxv, minv, diff, tot = 0, runs = 0;
    int count[6] = { 0 };
    for(a=1; a<=6; a++) {
        for(b=1; b<=6; b++) {
            for(c=1; c<=6; c++) {

                maxv = a;
                if(maxv < b) maxv = b;
                if(maxv < c) maxv = c;

                minv = a;
                if(minv > b) minv = b;
                if(minv > c) minv = c;

                diff = maxv - minv;
                count[diff]++;
                tot += diff;
                runs++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Average %f\n", (double)tot / runs);

    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        printf("%d %4d\n", i, count[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Average 2.916667
0    6
1   30
2   48
3   54
4   48
5   30
```